# Printing variables in Forward_gpu in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I want to print blobs of some layer in forward_gpu function in caffe, however I recieve segmentation fault in doing so.

```
template<typename Dtype>
void layer_name<Dtype>::Forward_gpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top)
{
    const Dtype* data_pointer = this->blobs_[0]->gpu_data();
    std::cout<<data_pointer[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

I have made sure that the blobs is resized and allocated space in the layer setup function

```
template<typename Dtype>
void layer_name<Dtype>::Forward_gpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top)
{
     this->blobs_.resize(1);
     vector<int> blob_size; 
     blob_size.push_back(1024); blob_size.push_back(8);
     this->blobs_[0].reset(new Blob<Dtype>(blob_size));
     Initilise_data(this->blobs_[0].get());
}
```

and have filled in the required data in the blob.
Any idea why would I be recieving seg fault ?

```
*** Aborted at 1519149857 (unix time) try "date -d @1519149857" if you are    using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7fe56e99c9df caffe::patchFieldLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
*** SIGSEGV (@0x10262a00000) received by PID 40338 (TID 0x7fe56f1d6ac0) from PID 1654652928; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe56d0da4b0 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe56e99c9df caffe::layer_name<>::Forward_gpu()
    @     0x7fe56e94f312 caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
    @     0x7fe56e94f427 caffe::Net<>::Forward()
    @     0x7fe56e7f2e9a caffe::Solver<>::Test()
    @     0x7fe56e7f385e caffe::Solver<>::TestAll()
    @     0x7fe56e7f397c caffe::Solver<>::Step()
    @     0x7fe56e7f44b6 caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
    @           0x40bc7f train()
    @           0x40772e main
    @     0x7fe56d0c5830 __libc_start_main
    @           0x4080b9 _start
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are accessing gpu_data in cpu code. You are supposed to print the data in the following way:

```
const Dtype* data_pointer = this->blobs_[0]->cpu_data();
std::cout<<data_pointer[0]<<std::endl;
```